Finding the maximum product of an array element and a distance
An array of integers is given. It is necessary to find the maximum product of the distance between a pair of elements and the minimum element of this pair.
For example, [2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2] -> 20, 5 and 5  (5 * (5-1)); [1, 2] -> 1
In the first example, the maximum product is obtained if we take 5 and 5(a[1] and a[5]). The minimum element of the pair is 5. The distance between the elements: 5 - 1 = 4. Result: 5 * 4 = 20
In the second example, there is only one pair. The minimum element is 1. The distance between the elements is 1. Result: 1*1 = 1
not an effective solution:
a = [2,5,2,2,1,5,2]
res = -10**9
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        res = max(res, min(a[i],a[j])*(j-i))

print(res)

The code is slow to work. How can I make it more efficient?

What do you mean "pass through time"?

In the first example, the maximum product is obtained if we take 5 and 5(a[1] and a[5]). The minimum element of the pair is 5. The distance between the elements: 5 - 1 = 4. Result: 5 * 4 = 20

In the second example, there is only one pair. The minimum element is 1. The distance between the elements is 1. Result: 1*1 = 1

What constraints are there on the elements of a? Are they all positive? Strictly positive? Integers or floats?

@lastchance 0 >= a[i] >= 10 000

@Artem Then the array must be empty. Do you mean <= instead of >=? Also, how long is the array (min length and max length)?

@nocomment
0 <= a[i] <= 10 000 (Sorry),
2 <= len(a) <= 100 000

So some a[i] could be 0?

@lastchance Yes

O(n log n):
from itertools import accumulate
from bisect import bisect_left

a = [2,5,2,2,1,5,2]

print(max(
    x * (j - bisect_left(m, x))
    for a in [a, a[::-1]]
    for m in [list(accumulate(a, max))]
    for j, x in enumerate(a)
))

Attempt This Online!
Assume the best pair has the smaller-or-equal value as the right value. For each right value, find the furthest left value larger or equal (so that the right value is indeed smaller or equal) and evaluate that pair. Do the whole thing both for the given array and for it reversed, which covers the case that the best pair has the smaller-or-equal value as the left value.
Inspired by Nijat Mursali's opening paragraph.

All tests passed

You definitely don't need to compare every possible pair, but rather focus on finding the maximum distance for each possible minimum value.
You more need to focus on the indices where a local minimum occurs and compute the distance between them and other elements and traverse through the array to track the farthest occurrences of each element. Lastly, for each element, compute the product of its value and the maximum distance it can produce with any other element (before or after it).
def maxProductOfMinAndDistance(a):
    n = len(a)
    left = [-1] * n
    right = [-1] * n
    
    # Initialize stack to maintain the indices of elements in the array
    stack = []
    
    # Fill left array
    for i in range(n):
        while stack and a[stack[-1]] >= a[i]:
            stack.pop()
        if stack:
            left[i] = stack[-1]
        stack.append(i)
    
    stack = []
    
    # Fill right array
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        while stack and a[stack[-1]] >= a[i]:
            stack.pop()
        if stack:
            right[i] = stack[-1]
        stack.append(i)
    
    # Compute the maximum product (third point)
    max_product = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if left[i] != -1:
            max_product = max(max_product, a[i] * (i - left[i]))
        if right[i] != -1:
            max_product = max(max_product, a[i] * (right[i] - i))
    
    return max_product


# Example 
a = [2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2]
print(maxProductOfMinAndDistance(a))  # Outputs 20



Need to note that this is O(n) linear in time complexity, as both left and right arrays are computed in O(n) time, and the final maximum product computation is also O(n).

It produces an incorrect result on large input data.

Could you please provide sample data?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WSe2WJ2ZioI12elg_J2vXWX_1ZfET2N/view?usp=drive_link

The iterative algorithm gives a different answer

What should be the result for this data?

The iterative algorithm: 934833,
Your algorithm: 6848

That is interesting, thanks for sharing. I will have a look at it and if I find answer I will update it.

@Artem Could you make that data accessible without having to log in, to anyone with the link?

@nocomment https://dpaste.com/D2LZ8DR3N

You can try this one. It has the same nominal order, but it reduces the search range substantially if a[i] is small. It also does no more multiplies than it absolutely needs to evaluate a new "best product".
In the inner loops, a[i] is always the candidate smaller value. It then does limited search ranges above and below. For example, looking "above" index i, we will need an index j such that a[i].(j-i)>best, or
j>i+best/a[i] to have any chance of improving the current best. We then find the last j such that a[j] >= a[i] and only does the multiply for this last j. Similarly when it looks for product pairs with j<i.
I've compared with your iterative solution and also your "large" test case (which was a bit long to include in the code here).
import math

def iterative( a ):
    res = -10**9
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
            res = max(res, min(a[i],a[j])*(j-i))
    return res


def bestProduct( a ):
    best = 0
    for i in range( len( a ) ):
        if a[i] == 0: continue                                      # dratted edge case

        jup = max( i + 1, math.ceil ( i + best / a[i] ) )         # reduce the search range ABOVE
        if jup < len( a ):
            jbest = i
            for j in range( jup, len( a ) ):
                if ( a[j] >= a[i] ): jbest = j                      # want the INDEX of the furthest that is >= a[i]
            if jbest != i: best = a[i] * ( jbest - i )

        jdown = min( i - 1, math.floor( i - best / a[i] ) )         # reduce the search range BELOW
        jbest = i
        if jdown >= 0:
            for j in range( jdown, -1, -1 ):
                if ( a[j] >= a[i] ): jbest = j
            if jbest != i: best = a[i] * ( i - jbest )

    return best


a = [2,5,2,2,1,5,2]
# print( iterative( a ) )              # Uncomment to compare
print( bestProduct( a ) )

Output (simple case):
20

Output (large case):
934833


Does not work on [1, 2]

I had to edit it @Artem. It should work now. I'll need to be more careful with the edge cases.

All tests passed
